# I have to bring text from any other app into my app through SHARE-TO method

Tags: android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I want to perform tasks in the background in my app without open ui.
You have to bring text from any other app into your app through shareTo method.

here is my code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
.
.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
.
.
.

<receiver
    android:name=".TextShareReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name=".TextService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
```

BroadcastReceiver  Code--

```
public class TextShareReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String type = intent.getType();
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                if (sharedText != null) {
                    // Process the received text/plain data here
                    Log.d("ShareReceiver", "Received shared text/plain data: " + sharedText);

                    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, TextService.class);
                    serviceIntent.putExtra("text_data", sharedText);
                    context.startService(serviceIntent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Service Code--

```
public class TextService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            String textData = intent.getStringExtra("text_data");
            if (textData != null) {
                // Process the received text/plain data here
                Log.d("YourService", "Received text/plain data: " + textData);
                // I want to save this text in the database through service. 
            }
        }

       return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

With this code I am not able to show the icon of my app in the shareTo option.

When I do it in the intent filter activity, the app icon shows up.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ReceiverActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I want to perform a task without opening the activity.